# Dropdown using Ajax in Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, dropdown

Can't find the error, it has to be with the query at "comunas" data base.

Here are the codes:

1) The 2 tables:

comunas:
comId   comNombre   comRegion

regiones:
regId   regNombre

2) Controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Usuarios extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model("regiones_model");
    $this->load->model("comunas_model");

}

public function index_get()
{       
    $data['regionDrop'] = $this->getRegiones();
     //loads up the view with the query results
    $this->load->view('panel/usuario_agrega_view',$data);
 }

    public function getRegiones()
{

    $this->db->select('regId,regNombre');
    $this->db->from('regiones'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
     // the query mean select cat_id,category from category
     foreach($query->result_array() as $row){
        $data[$row['regId']]=$row['regNombre'];
    }
    // the fetching data from database is return
    return $data;
}
    public function getComunaByRegion($regId=string)
{
    $this->db->select('comId,comNombre, comRegion');
    $this->db->from('comuna');
    $this->db->where('comRegion',$regId); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
         //call to fill the second dropdown with the comunas
public function buildDropComunas()
{
     //set selected country id from POST
  echo $regId = $this->input->post('id',TRUE);

    //run the query for the comunas we specified earlier
   $districtData['districtDrop']=$this->comunas_model->getComunaByRegion($regId);
   $output = null;

    foreach ($districtData['districtDrop'] as $row)
    {
        //here we build a dropdown item line for each query result
        $output .= "<option value='".$row->comNombre."'>".$row->comNombre."</option>";
    }

    echo  $output;
}
}
```

3) Models: I'm not using the querys at models, I can't "touch them" for now, so I'm putting that code direct in the controller.

4) View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
            $("#regionesDrp").change(function(){

                 /*dropdown post *///
                  $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url();?>usuarios/buildDropComunas",
                 data: {id: $(this).val()},
                type: "POST",
                success:function(data){

                    $("#comunaDrp").html(data);
                }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>

    <!--country dropdown-->
    <?php 
    echo form_dropdown('regionesDrp', $regionDrop,'','class="required" id="regionesDrp"');  ?>
```

I tried to follow the example from: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/225740/cascading-drop-down-in-codeigniter-using-ajax/

But I have a different database (FK comId) and as I told you, I can't use a model file for this. Anyway, I tried with a region_model and comuna_model but it's the same.

Comment: what is   #comunaDrp

Comment: Sorry, I already fixed. I had several errors, goint to edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Use append() not html()

```
$("#comunaDrp").append(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the function getComunaByRegion should be:

```
public function getComunaByRegion($comRegion=string)
{
    $this->db->select('comId,comNombre');
    $this->db->from('comunas');
    $this->db->where('comId',$comRegion);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Plus, in the controller, the function public function buildDropComunas_post() wasn't called with POST, that was the main reason of my 404 not found.